# Проблема отображения миниатюр записей в Wordpress плагином WP Popular Posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

При заливке сайта на рабочий хостинг в блоке популярных записей не отображаются некоторые миниатюры записей. При инспекции обнаружилось следующее сообщение:

**unable to open image `/home/projects/blog/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/4311-featured-310x210.jpg': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в какую сторону копать? Насколько я понимаю это не связано с самим WP, это настройки веб-сервера, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: переносил с локального? Как?

Comment: @SeVlad Не с локального, с хостинга на хостинг. Просто к первому хостингу и его настройкам есть доступ, ко второму, клиентскому доступа нет. 
На родном хостинге:
upload_max_filesize = 20M
На клиентском:
upload_max_filesize = 2M
Может ли это быть проблемой?

Comment: переноси с пом https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ и всё будет как надо